# best way to take Facebook api data and convert the string to a assigned integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

what is the best way to convert the call back from facebook string into integers

```
    user = User.new(email: user_data['email'], 
                    uid: user_data['id'],
                    provider: 'facebook', firstName: 
                    user_data['first_name'],
                    last_name: user_data['last_name'], 
                    gender: user_data['gender'],
                    password: Devise.friendly_token[0, 20])
```

i wanna take the gender and if its 'male' assign it to a number, if its 'female' assign it to another number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a `if`:

```
code = nil
if user_data['gender'] == 'male'
  code = 1
else
  code = 2
end
```

or use a Hash for the same result:

```
genders = { 'male' => 1, 'female' => 2 }

code = genders[user_date['gender']]
```

Comment: literally came to me after i posted as part of a before save, i like the hash version better, than the first one which is what i thought of, ty